# Is it a good design to use Google Guavas Predicates to decouple filter methods from classes

Tags: java, guava, predicate, software-design, open-closed-principle

Today I wrote the following [article](http://codesnipjes.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/google-guavas-predicates-and-the-open-closed-principle/) in my blog about how Google Guavas Predicates can be used to increase the extensibility of your design. This made me ask myself the following question: "Is the need for this solution caused by a deeper design flaw?". Is there another "cleaner" way of achieving this type of extensibility? Am I just thinking too deep about this?

Comment: The [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is another way to solve the problem in your Person/Persons blog example, and is entirely Object Orientated.  

Another would be a filter with [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  

I don't see any design flaw, as for cleaner you'll have to wait for Java 8 to remove boilerplate code but this has no effect on the conceptual level of design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) adds several things to Java that *should have* been there but weren't (many of which are included in v7).

IMO Guava tends to be very clean and fast. Compare Guava's [`ComparisonChain`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.java) with (for instance) Apache Commons `CompareToBuilder` classes. Both do essentially the same thing. While Apache's is very simple and easy enough for newbies to understand, Guava's is the faster/cleaner/less-resource-intensive (better?) approach.

As far as `Predicate`s go, they serve a function and they do it well, especially when you combine it with all of the other Guava stuff like [`Iterators.filter`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Predicates).

The Guava tools do need to be understood before they are used though. For instance, if you are going to loop through the filtered list multiple times and your `Predicate` has a non-negligible cost (CPU/memory/time), then you may be better off looping through it once and storing the values in a `Collection` first, as some of these methods just wrap the given `Iterable` into a class whose `next()` function just calls `next()` on the unfiltered `Iterable` until it finds an entry that passes the filter and returns that.

So, yes, Guava is very useful. Including `Predicate`s and `Iterables` and `Collections2` filtering, etc. However, it always helps to know what is going on under the hood and what gotchas or performance implications you may need to deal with if you find that your code needs optimization.